# Variable capacitor notation with a division sign (e.g. 2÷10p)

Tags: capacitor, schematics

In [this schematic](http://lea.hamradio.si/~s53mv/zifssb/kband/k01.gif), there is an unfamiliar notation for the variable capacitors using and division sign or obelus, for example 2÷10p (red), as opposed to, e.g. 1p for a fixed capacitor (green).

[image: Schematic fragment]

I have presumed that this is used for indicating the number of air gaps in a rotary variable capacitor, as the total capacitance is the capacitance of one gap, divided by the number of gaps (or plates - 1):

\$\frac{C_{one\ gap}}{n_{gaps}} = \frac{C_{one\ gap}}{n_{plates} - 1} = C_{total}\$

Is this the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Occam's razor, I would interpret the markings as the range of capacitance for the trimmers, and that it's a regional or idiosyncratic use of **÷** rather than **~** or **-**.

This is confirmed by the text on the website- for example [here](http://lea.hamradio.si/~s53mv/zifssb/sband.html).

> Capacitive trimmers (Philips foil type, 7.5mm diameter with three leads) in the 106MHz and 213MHz bandpass filters are increased to 5-40pF (violet body), while the trimmers in the output stage at 425MHz are increased to 4-20pF (green body).

Mechanical engineers sometimes indicate ranges by putting one number above the other, separated by a horizontal line, which, of course, is what **÷** is shorthand for.